# Get number from address boook

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to get number of choose user from phone book. For now I can only get his First name.

```
- (IBAction) showPhoneBook: (id)sender {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
    (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

// Select phone number
NSString* name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                               kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

self.number.text = name;

[name release];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
  (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                            property:(ABPropertyID)property
                          identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
return NO;
}
```

How can I to get number instead of first name?

Best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the phone number from the record you could do (inside your callback method):

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumberProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSArray* phoneNumbers = (NSArray*)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneNumberProperty);
CFRelease(phoneNUmberProperty);

// Do whatever you want with the phone numbers
NSLog(@"Phone numbers = %@", phoneNumbers);
[phoneNumbers release];
```

**UPDATE**

```
ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSString* mobile=@"";
NSString* mobileLabel;
for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {
        mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
        if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
        {
                [mobile release] ;
                mobile = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
        }
```

Comment: How can I get only mobile phone without parathesis and "

Comment: is there a way to check if the phone number is valid to send SMS to?

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
ABPersonViewController *pvc = [[[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    pvc.displayedPerson=contact.phonenumbers;
```